# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'params_proto.neo_proto'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

Trying to run

```
$ python -c "import kaze"
```

yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/jovyan/work/simple-env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kaze/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from params_proto.neo_proto import 
ParamsProto, Proto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'params_proto.neo_proto'
```

What module do I need to import to solve the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `params-proto` package in order to run `python -c "import kaze"` successfully:

```bash
pip install params-proto
```

---

The packages `kaze` and `params-proto` are maintained by the same person on GitHub:

- Repo params_proto: https://github.com/geyang/params_proto
- Repo kaze: https://github.com/geyang/kaze

Comment: Still getting the same error after installing params-proto